# i have this Exception : Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.instance.lifecycle; version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7.1

I'm using liferay 7.1 ga3.

In the build.gradle I need to use :

```
`compileOnly group:"com.liferay",name:"com.liferay.portal.instance.lifecycle",version: '3.0.0'
```

because I want to use `BlockchainPortalInstanceLifecycleListener`.

If I use the above, it throws the exception.

If I use like this

```
compileInclued group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.instance.lifecycle",version: '3.0.0'
```

instead,
 it does not throw the exception, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, compile include should not be necessary if you are using a dependency that is part of the modules exposed by liferay.
Second, the bundle exposed by 7.1 GA3 is not called

```
"com.liferay.portal.instance.lifecycle"
```

But you do have those available:

```
"com.liferay:com.liferay.portal.instance.lifecycle.api:1.0.+"
"com.liferay:com.liferay.portal.instance.lifecycle.impl:1.0.+"
```

You are probably looking for

```
compile "com.liferay:com.liferay.portal.instance.lifecycle.api:1.0.+"
```

Comment: ...and definitely do **not** go with `compileInclude`. The module is available in the OSGi runtime and *must not* be contained again in your own code.